# BootstrapValidator for bootstrap typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, validation, typeahead.js, typeahead

I want to know if BootstrapValidator http://bootstrapvalidator.com/ has a validation for typeahead.

I have a form where where i am validating my fields using the validator. One of the fields is a inout field where a typeahead is attached so the input field is filled by the typeahead select.

But whenever I start typing in the input field the validator validates its true. I want something like it must validates only after typeahead selection and not by writing in the the input field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {};
        options.common = {
            minChar: 1
        };
        options.ui = {
            showVerdictsInsideProgressBar : true,
            viewports : {
                progress : ".pwstrength_viewport_progress"
            }
        };
        .......
        $('#user_country').on('input', function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.small').hide();
        });
        $('#user_reg_form').bootstrapValidator({
            excluded: ':disabled',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
               ........
                country: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'city is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        })
```

My typeahead looks like

```
 $(ele).typeahead({
   select:function(){
        // here i do the select.....
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using a date picker - you could try manually binding the validation - e.g:

```
$('#userCountry').on('blur', function(e) {
    $('#user_reg_form').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'userCountry');
});
```

Does your typeahead control limit them to one of the options in the list?